# Mailparse is not being detected despite the DLL being in php/ext and the extension being enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension

As the title says, I have put `mailparse.dll` inside `C:\xampp\php\ext`. This should be the correct location for extension files. Then I also enabled it in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`, which is the `php.ini` file being used; I confirmed it with `phpinfo()`.

I am lost as to why I'm still getting the error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mailparse.dll' (tried: ext\php_mailparse.dll (The specified module could not be found.), ext\php_php_mailparse.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Also, I want to point out that I tried both `extension=mailparse` and `extension=php_mailparse.dll` in the `php.ini` file and neither worked.

Comment: Ok, so which dll? Did you check it is compiled with the correct version of the compiler, same version os PHP? Is it the correct 32bit or 64bit that matches your PHP and did you check it is the Thread Safe version and not the NonThread Safe version?

Comment: Oh bruh, I had the Non Thread Safe version when I needed the Thread Safe one. Didn't know it wouldn't load at all. Thx